# convexity analysis of trace inverse

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I know that for a matrix positive definite variable $X$, $\mathrm{tr}(X^{-1})$ is a convex function. Now I want to consider the following function:

$f(X) = \frac{(\mathrm{tr} (A X^{-1}))^2}{\mathrm{tr} (B X^{-1})}$

where $A$ and $B$ are also positive definite matrices. Could we say anything about its convexity/concavity?

My effort: I tried to take the second derivative of the above function but it seems to become very complicated.

Comment: I doubt it is convex, and it cannot be proven so using well-known composition rules.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy to construct a counterexample using a symbolic computation package.  Let

$A=\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
10 & 0 \\
0  & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]$

$B=\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0  & 10 \\
\end{array}
\right]$

And consider matrices

$X=\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
X_{1,1} & 0 \\
0  & X_{2,2} \\
\end{array}
\right]$

At $X_{1,1}=1$, $X_{2,2}=1$, the Hessian is

$H=\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
52.73 & -14.72 \\
-14.72  & -1.27 \\
\end{array}
\right]$

which is clearly not positive semidefinite and also not negative semidefinite.  Thus the function is not convex or concave in general.